# Why do all grid views get updated on adding item from common list control in active gridview in wpf?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a bind object of observable collection to my data grid view. But I am not able to figure out where issue exactly occurs. As I bind collection objects to grid views and when I add an item from list control in active grid view (**Grid present in one tab**), at the same time all grid views get reflected with newly added record in all tabs.

i have created 2 view models and 2 user controls. 1st (common view) user control contains ComboBox control.

2nd view contains Gridview.

View2.cs=

View2ViewModel _vIewModel= new View2ViewModel(EventAggrtorService.Instance.EventAggregator,                                    _vIewModel,DataCollection);

this.mydtGrid.ItemsSource = _vIewModel.DataCollection;

public ObservableCollection DataCollection = new ObservableCollection();

In 1st view model i have publish event to send selected item from combobox control and 2nd view model have subscriber.logic to insert data in gridview.

Problem occurs when i click on ribbon button (it create new window and executes 2ndViewModel constructor) for new tab to open then that new window got subscribed for event i publish from view 1. hence all views calls logic to **InsertData** i selected from combo control.hence all views shows new record.

public 2ndViewModel(IEventAggregator evAggrtor ,ObservableCollection DataCollection)

```
    {       
        this._eventAggregator = evAggrtor;
        this.DataCollection =DataCollection;

        SubscriptionToken token = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectedItemEvent2>().Subscribe(FillLookUpObject,
              Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.Events.ThreadOption.PublisherThread);
    }
```

Comment: welcome to SO! please read: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and correct your question according to instruction

Comment: Show us some code to help you.

Comment: In case you've bound all views to the same ObservableCollection instance, this is exactly the expected behavior.